# How can I change 0 to other numeric?

Tags: r

I have this simple example:

```
ds$drink0
[1] 13  56  0   5
```

What I want to do it to change the `0` value to a different numeric value, for example 0.1.

How can I do this?

Comment: paste the code that you have tried

Comment: You means this?paste(ds$drink0)

Comment: `ds$drink0[ds$drink0 == 0] <- 0.1`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers, post as answer?

Comment: @MauritsEvers In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ds$drink0 == 0, value = c(14L, 50L, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: It makes error. I'm so sad...

Comment: @Ben Bolker Do you know how can I do?

Comment: please edit your answer to include the results of `str(df$drink0)`. The fact that `drink0` is a factor means that something probably went wrong when you imported your data frame ...

Comment: @BenBolker & @jiyoung Posted solution and included an example for the case where `df$drink0` is a `factor`.

Comment: @Ben Bolker &@Maurits Evers Thankyou so much. God bless you!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `0`s with `0.1` in your vector `ds$drink0` with:

```
ds$drink0[ds$drink0 == 0] <- 0.1
```

This will work for numeric and character vectors.

If `ds$drink0` is a `factor` you can do:

```
ds$drink0 <- as.numeric(as.character(ds$drink0));
ds$drink0[ds$drink0 == 0] <- 0.1
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. I can change 0 to 0.1 now! Your my savior!